# TMDB API elements are not displaying on screen - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using TMDB and I'm trying to display pictures (posters) of top rated movies, but it isn't displaying anything. In console I check if there are elements and there were but nothing is displaying. I followed this video for instruction but I have no clue why is it not working for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ0bZGfg_m4

Here is my current code:

App.js:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movie from './components/Movie';

//due to it being a demo project I will not safe keep the API
const API ="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1";
const SEARCH_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&query=";
const TOP_RATED_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1"

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  fetch(TOP_RATED_API)
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    setMovies(data.result);
  });

},[]);

  
 
  return <div>{movies?.length > 0 && movies.map((movie)=>
  <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie}/>
  )}</div>
  
 
}

export default App;
```

and Movie.js:

```
import React from "react";
const IMG_API="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";

const Movie =({title, backdrop_path, vote_average})=>
(
    <div>
        <img src={IMG_API+backdrop_path} alt={title}/>
    </div>
);


export default Movie;
```

After changing the last part in App.js ->

```
return <div>{movies?.length > 0 && movies.map((movie)=>
      <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie}/>
      )}</div>
```

to this (removed ? after movies)

```
return <div>{movies.length > 0 && movies.map((movie)=>
          <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie}/>
          )}</div>
```

it displays an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance :D

Comment: console.log(movies) before you return and see what's in it.

Comment: @Matt an empty array

Comment: I got "Image size not supported" when I tried to access some of the files directly on the browser, maybe it's the issue

Comment: @Dani try if w=500 or w=1280 instead of w=1300, I have edited the question where to change, if that doesn't work try poster_path instead of backdrop_path

Comment: Empty array should have a .length. (It's not undefined) Are you sure the error corresponds with that line?

Comment: @Matt it says [], length:0, _proto__: Array(0)

Comment: If you go into network tab within dev tools, do you see the API call being made and returning with correct data?

Comment: I think so, around 1000ms it has the api and here is the info: Request URL: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 13.32.14.12:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a typo, it is data.results not data.result

```
useEffect(()=>{


fetch(TOP_RATED_API)
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    setMovies(data.results);
  });

},[]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going over the code scratching my head, once again thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it was a typo. result should have been results.

Without that you were setting movies to undefined.

Here's a runnable version that works.

```js
//due to it being a demo project I will not safe keep the API
const API = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1";
const SEARCH_API = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&query=";
const TOP_RATED_API = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1"

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(TOP_RATED_API)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("inside use effect", res);
        setMovies(res.results);
      });

  }, []);


console.log(movies);
  return movies && <div > {
    movies.map((movie) => <Movie key = {movie.id} { ...movie}  />)
  } < /div>
}

const IMG_API = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";

const Movie = ({
    title,
    backdrop_path,
    vote_average
  }) =>
  ( <div>
    <img src = {IMG_API + backdrop_path} alt = {title} /> 
    </div>
  );

ReactDOM.render( <App / > , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is the erro: Unhandled Rejection (Error): App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: Also it says that here is an anonymous function:   .then((res)=>res.json())
  15 |   .then((data)=>{
  16 |     console.log(data);
> 17 |     setMovies(data.result);
  18 |   });
  19 | 
  20 | },[]);